# How can I push 1903 to1909 windows update through Intune on hybrid env?

Tags: azure, windows-10, azure-active-directory, intune

Using hybrid env, would like to use inTune function to push updates 1903 to 1909.
Would like to push for upto 50 machines together.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure policies to assign the Windows updates, if that's how you are hoping to manage this.

From [Create and assign Windows 10 feature updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/windows-update-for-business-configure):

1. Sign in to the Microsoft Endpoint Manager admin center.
2. Select Devices > Windows > Windows 10 Feature updates > Create.
3. Under Basics, specify a name, a description (optional), and for Feature update to deploy, select the version of Windows with the feature set you want, and then select Next.
4. Under Assignments, choose + Select groups to include and then assign the feature update deployment to one or more groups. Select Next to continue.
5. Under Review + create, review the settings and select Create when ready to save the Windows 10 feature updates policy.

You can also review the [policy overview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itshowcase/keeping-windows-10-devices-up-to-date-with-microsoft-intune-and-windows-update-for-business).

Let me know if this helps and is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much Marilee for answering my question here, However are refering altest Intune as Microsoft endpoint manager admin center or some other console ? I am planning to deply this on HYBRID ENVIRONMENT FROM MY azure intune portal ? Hope you find this more detail and help me here? 
?